# Unresolved dependencies in Android Studio project

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

**Issue:** I've recently updated/installed the latest version of Android Studio and I imported a little old project. **When I sync the project I get these errors:**

[image]

The errors are as follows:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.0.1
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:12.0.1
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app

I tried to add all the necessary elements to the gradle and I tried installing Google Play Services in SDK. My project is imported from the Desktop.

**This is my app/build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.albetaqasite"

        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : 'cc95bb51-0699-4309-9322-be8793d5e564',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE']


        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 55
        versionName "3.4.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    implementation project(':ColorDialog')
    implementation files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    //implementation 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.8.3, 3.99.99]'
   // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:8.4.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is my Project/build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

P.S: I'm aware of the problem in android.com.support dependencies, when I change the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `27` it works, but the gradle ones I couldn't fix, kindly share your knowledge and experience if you've ever encountered this or have any idea how to solve it.

Comment: You can try with migrating to androidx.

Comment: I did that, I still have that error showing up..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add entries for those dependencies down in the section near these entries:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
```

However, if you try to bring in version 12.0.1 of one library, and version 8.4.0 of another related library, you are probably going to have issues.  See if you can bump up the version number of these three to 12.0.1

Comment: I tried that before and I tried it now after freshly importing the project, it gives me the first error only. which is this one: `Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.0.1 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app`

Comment: The latest version I see that has been released to Maven is com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0, so, maybe you need to look for a more updated version?  Check here for the libraries you need:  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases